# framework yii, ошибка

Tags: yii

создал тестовый проект, открыл его в браузере, вот что выдало, подскажите в чем беда
[image]

Comment: а если закинуть строку с ошибкой в переводчик то что будет написано?

Comment: умный самый нашелся ))) как и всегда, я переводчиком умею пользоваться

Comment: ну так и что же написано в переводчике?

Comment: ну то что нет файла этого, или директории

Comment: ну и что из этого тебе тогда не понятно? неправильный путь значит или отсутствие оного совсем

Comment: ну как исправить эту беду мне не понятно ))) не надо говорить только, чтоб я создал это ) изначально не собирается проект и это не хорошо))) думаю если подумать головой это можно понять )

Comment: ну как как - поставить корректный путь.....как же еще.....есть ли по такому пути файл или директория? если если нет - всё понятно. если есть - либо права на директорию плохие, либо всё равно путь не так указал (например не от корня директории). ..... или ты хочешь чтоб по данному стектрейсу плохо отображаемому на картинке сказали где конкретно в твоем проекте ошибка?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Похоже на неверную настройку или каталога корня сайта в веб сервере, или параметры самого Yii не корректно настроены на пути к публичной части/файлам. Есть несколько типов шаблонов, в частности, когда публичная часть сайта на уровень глубже и вариантов много разных. Мало информации, чтобы сказать точно... Проверяйте настройки рекомендуемые в шаблоне, который вы используете для Yii и веб сервера.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по картинке, корневой каталог сайта указывает на папку ...\htdocs\ возможно настройки по умолчанию для xampp, надо изменить корень сайта в настройка веб сервера на каталог где лежит index.php шаблона Yii. И поглядеть еще какие настройки требуются для Yii, обычно в описании шаблона который вы используете.